# Files list file for package 'git' contains empty filename error

Tags: raspberry-pi, dpkg

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 running Raspian Lite Version 10. So I far I have installed git, Apache, php, and phpmyadmin on it.

Now while trying to install python3-venv package (or any package for that matter) using `sudo apt-get install python3-venv` I am getting following error -

`Selecting previously unselected package python-pip-whl. dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting: files list file for package 'git' contains empty filename E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)`

I am not able to install any package on my system due to this error. So far I tried deleting the git folder from /usr/bin/dpkg but it has not seemed to help.

Comment: Following advice in https://askubuntu.com/a/878446 seems to have solved my issue. sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/git.list & then  sudo apt-get install --reinstall git